# page colorbox field css differs in view

Tags: theming

I've noticed in views when displaying colorbox content images (post per gallery)the css never translates from the css displayed of that type in page or node.

In the page the colorbox thumbnail images have a white border but displayed inline within the view there is no border.

I've inspected the element as a field item but I can't work out how to

add the white border around thumbnails in the view?

Comment: oops I just worked it out, you have to in views select the "use field template"

Comment: do i delete this question or leave for someone with same problem......

Comment: Leave it I'd say.